# How to write this Join Constraint with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How should I write this with ActiveRecord:

```
select stores.id, stores.name, store_specials.active 
from stores 
left outer join store_specials on 
     (store_specials.store_id = stores.id and store_specials.special_id = 1) 
where stores.active = true;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rails 3.x**

```
Stores.select("stores.id, stores.name, store_specials.active").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN tore_specials ON store_specials.store_id = stores.id AND store_specials.special_id = 1).where("store_specials.active = true")
```

Hopefully this is what you need